# How to compare two Struct objects?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two objects for the same struct class having different values. I need to compare these two objects whether they are equal or not. Please guide me through a proper solution.

```
struct CustomerInfo {
   var billAddressCity: String?

   init(a:String?){
      billAddressCity = a

  }
}

 /* init object */
 var obj1 =  CustomerInfo?
 var obj2 =  CustomerInfo?

 obj1 = CustomerInfo(a: "ONE")
 obj2 = CustomerInfo(a: "TWO")

 /*  I need to compare these two objects */

 if obj1 == obj2 {
     Print(equal values)
  }
```

This is not the answer Iam looking for, as it says i need to compare each and every values of fields manually, 
[Compare two instances of an object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105272/compare-two-instances-of-an-object-in-swift)

Comment: Your struct needs to conform to the Equatable protocol to use '==' for comparision

Comment: _"This is not the answer I am looking for"_ Well, that's the answer regardless...

Comment: I absolutely get what's being asked here, and would like to do the same thing: when a struct has 30 attributes, I'd like to know if the attributes of obj1 are all equal to the same attributes of obj2, ***without*** having to write (and ***maintain!***) a 30-item-long comparison, like `obj1.abc == obj2.abc && obj1.bcd == obj2.bcd && ...`.  Seems like there ought to be an elegant way to do this!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the Object Oriented World, generally, all Objects are unique to each other.

So, how I could compare two objects?

Your struct/class need to implement the `Equatable` Protocol which let you define how an object could be equal to another object of the same class/struct

Let's begin with this House struct:

```
struct House {
    var street: String
}

var houseA = House(street: "street A, n. 10")
var houseB = House(street: "street A, n. 10")

houseA == houseB // of course you can't
```

With the `Equatable` protocol you can implement the `static func ==`. Here you can define how two object of the same class could be equal when you use the operator `==`.

In my example, two objects of the struct House could be equal when they have the same street:

```
struct House: Equatable {
    var street: String

    static func == (lhs: House, rhs: House) -> Bool {
        return lhs.street == rhs.street
    }
}  

var houseA = House(street: "street A, n. 10")
var houseB = House(street: "street A, n. 10")

houseA == houseB // now print true
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been closed.

But for structs, another option (which might be useful in certain situations is:)

func areStructsEqual<T1,T2>(s1: T1, s2: T2) -> Bool {
    var s1 = s1
    var s2 = s2
    let s1Data = Data(bytes: &s1, count: MemoryLayout<T1>.stride)
    let s2Data = Data(bytes: &s2, count: MemoryLayout<T2>.stride)
    
    return s1Data == s2Data
}

Basically the idea is comparing the raw data of the structs byte by byte. I tested this with ints, and then a few different types of custom structs.

Unfortunately I can't format the code here xD

Answer (score 6):

By conforming to `Equatable`:

```
struct CustomerInfo: Equatable {
    var billAddressCity: String?

    init(a:String?){
        billAddressCity = a
    }

    static func ==(lhs: CustomerInfo, rhs: CustomerInfo) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.billAddressCity == rhs.billAddressCity)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i call this method?

Comment: do i need to compare each and every field of structure? I'm looking for alternative way.

Comment: If you define `CustomerInfo` in this way, you can simply do `if obj1 == obj2`. This comparison will call `static func ==` and return results by comparing `billAddressCity`.

Comment: @Jan then how do you want to compare them? give us examples.