# Array contains method is not working properly with custom models and predicate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Hi I just recently faced a weird problem during my development.native contains not working properly.Below is my Code.

```
struct Hello {
    var name : String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var phone : String = ""

    init(name: String,address: String,phone: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
    }
}


struct Buddy {
    var phone : String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""

    init(name: String,address: String,phone: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
    }
}


var a: [Hello] = []
a.append(Hello(name: "Gaurav", address: "Address1", phone: "123456"))
a.append(Hello(name: "Kumar", address: "Address2", phone: "123457"))
a.append(Hello(name: "Singh", address: "Address3", phone: "123"))


var b: Buddy = Buddy(name: "Pawan", address: "Address1", phone: "123")
if (a.contains(where: { $0.phone != b.phone})) {
    print("doest not contain")
} else {
    print(" contain")
}
```

Actual result:
   print("doest not contain")

Expected Result:
   print("contain")

Comment: Please post the code rather than a link.

Comment: @vadian I have updated.. please check

Comment: I think `!a.contains(where: { $0.phone == b.phone})` will work based on your `if-else` statement

Comment: But `a` does contain elements where the phone number is different. Using contains with a negation, !=, is always troublesome. In plain English your code says, is there _any_ element that has a phone number that is different from b.phone

Comment: Please explain why you expect the output “contain”

Comment: add == in your struct like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074718/how-to-compare-two-struct-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct.

You are checking

> Does `a` contain a `Hello` whose phone number is **not** 123.

This is `true` because there are even two items with a different phone number

Answer (score 0):

Change the last part to:

```
if (a.contains(where: { $0.phone == b.phone})) {
    print("contains")
} else {
    print("does not contain")
}
```

and it will return the proper value.